# ArrayList of objects that all end up equaling the last object

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I am having a problem that I have been trying to fix for days. That problem is that when I create an ArrayList of objects in the end they all equal the last object. I believe that it has something to do with continuously adding the same object, but from what I can tell I am creating a new one each time.

The point of this program should be to make a bunch of different cells or for simulation purposes (people) that can later on interact with one another depending on their random attributes.

This is the code I am having trouble with

```
private ArrayList<Cell> cellsList = new ArrayList<Cell>(); //This appears before the Class is created
private int startingCellNumber = 10; //This appears before the Class is created

//This is inside the class
//Go through and create the starting cells
for(int index=0; index < startingCellNumber; index++) {
  cellsList.add(new Cell());
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, I know there are questions similar to this one on Stack Overflow, but all of the answers to those did not fix my problem.

Both of the full codes (written in Java Processing)
The Runner

```
private ArrayList<Cell> cellsList = new ArrayList<Cell>();
private int startingCellNumber = 10;

void setup() {
  //Set up the background stuff
  size(600,400);
  frameRate(30);
  noStroke();


  //Go through and create the starting cells
  for(int index=0; index < startingCellNumber; index++) {
    //Cell newCell = new Cell();
    cellsList.add(new Cell());
    System.out.println(index + " : " + cellsList.get(index).getColonyColor() + " : (" + cellsList.get(index).getLocation(0) + "," + cellsList.get(index).getLocation(1) + ")"); //Here to test the output
  }

  System.out.println("------------------");

  //Test to see where error lies
  for(int index=0; index < startingCellNumber; index++) {
    System.out.println(index + " : " + cellsList.get(index).getColonyColor() + " : (" + cellsList.get(index).getLocation(0) + "," + cellsList.get(index).getLocation(1) + ")");
  }
}
void draw() {
  //Refresh the background
  background(51);
  //Go through and draw all of the cells (will be moved to the draw function)
  for(Cell activeCell : cellsList) {
    activeCell.drawCell();
    //System.out.println(activeCell);
  }
}
```

The Cell Class

```
private int strength;
private int age;
private int reproduction;
private String colonyColor;
private boolean disease;
private int[] location = {0,0};

private String[] directions = {"LEFT","Right","Up","Down"};

class Cell {
  //This is the constructor for the cell class 
  Cell() {
    strength = (int)(Math.random()*8)+3;
    age = 0;
    reproduction = (int)(Math.random()*6)+0;
    colonyColor = pickColor();
    if(colonyColor.equals("BLUE")) { location[0] = (int)(Math.random()*591)+0; location[1] = (int)(Math.random()*391)+0; }
    else if(colonyColor.equals("RED")) { location[0] = (int)(Math.random()*591)+0; location[1] = (int)(Math.random()*391)+0; }
  }
  //This class will randomly pick a team color for the cell
  private String pickColor() {
    int randColorNum = (int)(Math.random()*2)+1;
    if(randColorNum == 1) { return "BLUE"; }
    else if(randColorNum == 2) { return "RED"; }
    else { return "BLUE"; }
  }
  //This method picks the direction in which the cell will move
  private void moveDirection() {
    String chosenDirection = directions[(int)(Math.random()*4)+0];

    if(chosenDirection.equals("Left")) { checkNewLocation(-1,0); }
  }
  //this method uses the direction given by moveDirection() and decides what to do with it
  private void checkNewLocation(int xChange,int yChange) {

  }

  public void drawCell() {
    //Changes color depending on cells colonyColor
    if (getColonyColor().equals("RED")) { fill(255,0,0); }
    else { fill(0,0,255); }
    //Should draw the cell
    //System.out.println(getLocation(0) + " " + getLocation(1));
    rect(getLocation(0), getLocation(1), 10, 10);
  }

  //All of the gets and set methods for the Cell class's variables
  public int getStrength() { return strength; }
  public void setStrength(int s) { strength = s; }
  public int getAge() { return age; }
  public void setAge(int a) { age = a; }
  public int getReproduction() { return reproduction; }
  public void setReproduction(int r) { reproduction = r; }
  public String getColonyColor() { return colonyColor; }
  public void setColonyColor(String c) { colonyColor = c; }
  public boolean getDisease() { return disease; }
  public void setDisease(boolean d) { disease = d; }
  public int getLocation(int index) { return location[index]; }
}
```

Comment: Did you override equals in the Cell class? Perhaps using the parameterless constructor to create 10 Cell instances created 10 instances all equal to each other.

Comment: I have tried adding an initial index integer to the cell class and then making that a parameter to make it different for all 10 cells, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please show the code of the Cell class

Comment: Well from the code you posted it is correct. `new Cell()` is always the same

Comment: I am trying to make new Cell() create a different cell each time though.

Comment: @NiVeR look at the cell class constructor. I think he's randomizing values.

Comment: Have you tried printing the object itself instead of its fields? I have doubts whether they are really the same object or just it is just the randoms that are returning the same values. ``System.out.println(cellsList.get(index))`` in one of the ``setup`` fors

Comment: I have and this is what I got from it Runner$Cell@73337102
Runner$Cell@197d27c8
Runner$Cell@110cd60a
Runner$Cell@6021c414
Runner$Cell@8721273
Runner$Cell@784127d2
Runner$Cell@7a90d40a
Runner$Cell@59467c50
Runner$Cell@3da6abf6
Runner$Cell@fffd473

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my code was that I created all of my Cell class variables before the `class Cell { }` line. By moving them after the line everything worked fine.